# Background URL dinamico

Tags: javascript, array

É possível criar um array dinâmico de imagens e o mesmo ser chamado dentro do background-image:url() ?

Com a dica que foi passada por @hugocsl anteriormente, gostaria de reutilizar esta linha de instrução porque ela faz parte de um loader de página ao qual utilizo e me é muito util,

```
#carrega_imagem {
        position: relative;            
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 0%, 
                                          rgba(102, 0, 0, .50) 100%),  
                                          url("images/casa_linda.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 100%;
        left: 100%;
}
```

Onde está o trecho do código `url("images/casa_linda.jpg")`, é possivel criar um array via javascript ?

Vi isso em Jquery, mas o que mata é a estrutura que uso para este loader.

Comment: Cara vc que só que a imagem fique alternando o tempo inteiro no fundo? Se é só isso da para fazer só com CSS e fazer uma animação com o background trocando as imagens... Se quiser um exemplo simples é só falar.

Answer (score 3):

É possível sim. Basta criar uma variável para armazenar os valores (link das fotos) e depois utilizar `for` para percorrer esses valores, por exemplo:

```js
/* Gradiente padrão */
const gradient = "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 0%, rgba(102, 0, 0, .50) 100%)";

/* Link das imagens */
const images = [
  'https://www.grammy.com/sites/com/files/styles/news_detail_header/public/news/lindsey_stirling_still_01.jpg?itok=cDdUKxXi',

  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/Evanescence_at_The_Wiltern_theatre_in_Los_Angeles%2C_California_04_%28cropped%29.jpg',

  'http://images.virgula.com.br/2018/03/63a8d811-2814-4cdf-9c9f-aeb31559854f.jpg'
];

/* Função para alterar as imagens */
(async () => {
    for (let image of images) {

      /* Aplica o gradiente com a URL da imagem */
      document.body.style.setProperty("background-image", `${gradient}, url('${image}')`);
      
      /* Define o tempo de 5 segundos para alternar */
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))

    }
})();
```

```css
body {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Com *jQuery* é a mesma coisa. Para alterar a propriedade basta usar

```
$("element").css("background-image", `${gradient}, url('${image}')`);
$("element").delay(5000);
```

---

Caso você queira uma imagem aleatória apenas (sem alternância), então você pode utilizar `Math.random` para capturar a imagem randomicamente, por exemeplo:

```js
/* Gradiente padrão */
const gradient = "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 0%, rgba(102, 0, 0, .50) 100%)";

/* Link das imagens */
const images = [
  'https://www.grammy.com/sites/com/files/styles/news_detail_header/public/news/lindsey_stirling_still_01.jpg?itok=cDdUKxXi',

  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/Evanescence_at_The_Wiltern_theatre_in_Los_Angeles%2C_California_04_%28cropped%29.jpg',

  'http://images.virgula.com.br/2018/03/63a8d811-2814-4cdf-9c9f-aeb31559854f.jpg'
];

const slider = document.querySelector("#slider");

/* Função para capturar e aplicar uma imagem aleatória */
slider.style.setProperty("background-image", `${gradient}, url('${images[ Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length) ]}')`);
```

```css
img {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<img id="slider">
```

---

Se você pretende ter uma imagem alternada com animação, segue exemplo:

```js
const slider = document.querySelector("#slider");

const images = slider.querySelector("img");

(async() => {
  for (;;) {

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))

    let elementCurrent = slider.querySelector(".active")
    let elementNext;

    if (elementCurrent.nextElementSibling) {
      elementNext = elementCurrent.nextElementSibling;
    } else {
      elementNext = images[0];
    }

    elementCurrent.classList.remove("active")
    elementNext.classList.add("active")
  }
})();
```

```css
#slider,
#slider .overlay {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
}

#slider img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

#slider img,
#slider .overlay {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0
}

#slider .overlay {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 0%, rgba(102, 0, 0, .50) 100%);
}

#slider img.active {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=845" class="active" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=844" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=843" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=842" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=841" />

  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Usei o `background-image`, mas ele não tem efeito de animação (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#animatable-properties). Caso deseje isto, é necessário utilizar outro método.

Comment: Putz eh isso que preciso ! Mas o meu caso é muito especifico, uso um loader chamado Queryloader, e fiz uma adaptacao onde carrego 2 imagens ao mesmo tempo + o gradiente,
#qLoverlay {  position: relative; background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 0%, rgba(102, 0, 0, .50) 100%), url("images/honeycomb.jpg"); background-size: cover; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 100%; left: 100%; }        
#qLoverlay::after {
            position: absolute; content: url(images/greetings.png); top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-left: -600px; margin-top: -600px; }

Comment: Eu precisaria chamar a função em javascript criada onde esta o URL do background-image

Comment: Eu queria algo do tipo desta função, mas eu não sei como instanciar a variável do script dentro da URL do background-image.

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
   
   var imgr = Math.round(Math.random()*4);

   var imgsrc = [
   'imagem1.jpg',
   'imagem2.jpg',
   'imagem3.jpg',
   'imagem4.jpg',
   'imagem5.jpg'];
  
    document.getElementById('eximg').src = imgsrc[imgr];
}
</script>

<img id="eximg"/>

Comment: Também tenho esse outro script aqui que poderia ser adaptado ...

<script language="JavaScript">
window.onload = function() {

 var randnum = Math.random();
 var inum = 5;

 var rand1 = Math.round(randnum * (inum-1)) + 1;
 images = new Array
 images[1] = "imagem1.jpg"
 images[2] = "imagem2.jpg"
 images[3] = "imagem3.jpg"
 images[4] = "imagem4.jpg"
 images[5] = "imagem5.jpg"

 var image = images[rand1]

 document.getElementById('img').src=image;
}
</script>

<img id="img" />

Comment: @EitaEhNOiz Você quer que seja uma imagem aleatória ou ela tem que ir alternando?

Comment: Sim, achei muito bacana o seu exemplo! Mas eu estou amarrado a uma estrutura em css, ao qual uso pseudo-elementos (::before e ::after) e que me ajudam muito e que o amigo @hugocsl ajudou a estruturar, e justamente no background-image=url(../images/minha.imagem.jpg) é que não consigo colocar um array.
Uso um loader chamado Queryloader2 para a abertura da pagina, e cada vez que a pagina for recarregada, gostaria que a imagem do fundo fosse trocada de forma aleatória.
E é justamente nesse background-image=url(), que não consigo / não sei instanciar a variável em Javascript dentro da url ();

Comment: #qLoverlay {
            position: relative;            
            background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 0%, rgba(102, 0, 0, .50) 100%), url("images/honeycomb.jpg");
            background-size: cover;            
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            top: 100%;
            left: 100%;
        }        
        #qLoverlay::after {
            position: absolute;
            content: url(images/logo.png);
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;           
            margin-left: -600px;
            margin-top: -600px; 
        }

Comment: A estrutura acima foi um complemento que cheguei graças ao @hugocsl. 
O problema está no url do #qLoverlay, onde o background-image:url("images/honeycomb.jpg) carrega a imagem. O ultimo código passado achei massa! Muito bom mesmo, mas eu nao sei como instanciar a variavel javascript dentro desta url () ...
Seria algo do tipo background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 0%, rgba(102, 0, 0, .50) 100%), url( variavel_javascript_aqui ?). 
Preciso estudar mais javascript, pois sei muito pouco. :(

Comment: O exemplo aleatorio ficou massa ! @Valdeir Psr, preciso disso em minha estrutura, entende ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="qLoverlay" class="preloader"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Gradiente padrão */
    const gradient = "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 0%, rgba(102, 0, 0, .50) 100%)";

    /* Link das imagens */
    const images = [
      'images/building.jpg', 
      'images/honeycomb.jpg',
      'images/space.jpg'];

    const slider = document.querySelector("#qLoverlay");

    /* Função para capturar e aplicar uma imagem aleatória */
    slider.style.setProperty("background-image", `${gradient}, url('${images[ Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length) ]}')`);
</script> 


<style type="text/css">

    /* ATENÇÃO = PSEUDO-ELEMENTOS - Exige o "::" */
    #qLoverlay {
        position: relative;            
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }

    #qLoverlay::after {
        position: absolute;
        content: url(images/logo.png);
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -600px;
        margin-top: -600px; 
    }
</style>
```

Aqui o importante é na div onde é apresentada a imagem de fundo para o meu caso, o QueryLoader2,  basta colocar um #ID, depois eh só apontar o const slider=document.querySelector("#qLoverlay") e por ultimo ajustar a classe / ID #qLoverlay no style CSS.

Comment: Muito obrigado aos amigo @hugocsl pela dica do css !

Comment: Obrigado também ao amigo @Valdeir Psr que disponibizou o script JS e a forma como fazer o random das imagens ! Valeu !!!!!